# Can't get an upload to Firebase/FireStorage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying (for the first time) to upload an image on firebase/storage, but with a very limited success.

I tried to follow this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

The code below is based on the paragraph titled *Full Example* at the bottom of the document.

But when I expect to see a image uploaded, I only get a ten bytes file, which is not displayable.
And it shows an error: Error loading preview 
when I click on it in the firebase console.

Since something gets written (with the correct name: *SoAf.jpg*) I know I have no permission issue. But obviously I am not doing what I should to get the image uploaded correctly.

It would be great if someone could see what is wrong in this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action='UpldTest3.html' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
National flag: <input type='file' accept='image/*' name='photo' id='photo'><br/>
<input type='submit' name='ValNatFlag' style='font-size:20px' value='Submit Picture'><br/>
</form>


<script>
    // Firebase Initialization :
    var config = {
      apiKey: "myyKeyyy",
      authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://......firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "....",
      storageBucket: "........appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "........."
    },
    app = firebase.initializeApp(config),
    db = firebase.firestore(app);
</script>

<script>

var file = new File(["fooFOO.jpg"], "SoAf.jpg", {type: "image/jpeg"});

// Create the file metadata
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/SoAf.jpg'
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {

  // A full list of error codes is available at
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    //...

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
      break;
  }
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just listen to file change and get the file

```
<img src="" id="imgPic" alt="" height="80px">
<input type='file' accept='image/*' name='photo' id='photo'>
```

This is the script

```
var fileToRead = document.getElementById("photo");

fileToRead.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById("imgPic");
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]) ;
  var tobeSaved = event.target.files[0] // save on storage
}, false);
```